# Wait until element doesn't exists using AjaxElementLocatorFactory

Tags: selenium

I'm using page factory and AjaxElementLocatorFactory in my selenium project. I would like to implement something like this:

```
@FindBy(className = "loading-container")
private WebElement loadingElement;

public LoadingPage(WebDriver driver) {
    AjaxElementLocatorFactory factory = new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 100);
    PageFactory.initElements(factory, this);
}

public void waitLoadingToFinish() {
    waitUntilElementDoesn'tExist(loadingElement);
}
```

Comment: why cant you use selenium inbuilt explicit wait? Something like below : WebElement element = wait.until( ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id(item)));

Comment: Because I'm looking for a solution using AjaxElementLocatorFactory and page factory. All my web components extends class that uses AjaxElementLocatorFactory and I would like to keep it that way. presenceOfElementLocated accepting only locator. Besides, I want to wait for the element to disappear from DOM.

Comment: I am not sure any inbuilt method is there to wait till any element disappears, however you can work with a combination of loop and IsElementVisible() method to wait till element is disappeared.

Comment: The problem with AjaxElementLocatorFactory is that each time I call a method for element, it waits for the element to appear. for exmaple something like that element.isDisplayed() waits for the element to show up (until timeout) and than invoke the method isDisplayed. so if the element doesn't exists it waits for nothing.